# Keeping track of total inventory, sales, etc; stored procedure or something like elastic search

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, stored-procedures

I'm creating an inventory management and sales tool for an e-commerce site.  I'm somewhat new to programming, and I'm curious what is the best way to keep track of totals.  For example this company sells roughly 200 products a day, and I would like to be able to keep track of the total amount of products sold in dollars, units sold, and eventually graph this data. I would like to be able to graph a month's worth of these numbers (may 14: 145 units sold, $14,545, $2000 profit, may 15: etc).  What is the best way of doing this?

I thought about creating a total's table, and every time a new order comes it adds order value to the previous total's amount, but this seems like it could get cloudy quick if an order doesn't get logged.

Doing a select all and adding the total's for each day for a month seems like it would be bad performance wise.

What options do I have and what do you recommend as the best solution?

Comment: Store the transactional data.  Summarize what you need using a query.

Comment: This is a very open-ended question, which is generally something to avoid on stackoverflow. You could improve the question by asking for a list of approaches, specifying a technology, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: If you are new to programming you should most likely  not be doing something really complex like this. Find an existing solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against creating a totals table. While building a report that summarizes the totals from the transactional data may seen to cause a performance problem, in practice it might not be nearly as bad as you think. Two hundred orders per day over thirty days really isn't all that many records for most modern relational database systems.

If you did run into a significant performance issue with this one report, one thing you could do would be to run the report during any off-hours that the business may have and then cache the results of that run in a table for use when someone wants to view the report. However, before going to that trouble I recommend just trying out what was mentioned above and see if performance is really even that much of an issue.